# Fuzzy logic using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, fuzzy-logic

I need to search thru the name list and find out the relevant matched names with the matching percentage.For example, if i have the name list like,

```
Ramu
Rahim
Raju
Ravan
Mustafa
```

if i give the name like Raheem,
it will find out the name Rahim and display the matching percentage like

```
Given Input:Raheem
Output:
Name Rahim match with the name Raheem 70%
```

Can i meet my requirement using MySql?

> Note:I have tried with the FullText search in mysql,But that search
>   match with only the words not by the characters

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't answer to your question directly, you may want to use [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) or [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone).

> Soundex is a phonetic algorithm for indexing names by sound, as
>   pronounced in English.

Comment: Maybe he could make a fulltext field, which contains each name transformed to soundex word-by-word, which could be quickly searched, ex: instead of indexing `Sir Arthur Conan Doyle`, index `S600 A636 C550 D400`.

Comment: SOUNDEX also exsits for mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Comment: Maybe a trigger would be the best solution, which would do the soundex conversion for indexing.

Comment: Hi ,select SOUNDEX('Raheem'),select SOUNDEX('Rahim'),select SOUNDEX('Ram').All the three retutn the index R500.I think it somewhat vague on my concept.Is there any other idea?

Comment: @MuneeswaranBalasubramanian Metaphone will return RHM, RHM, RM respectively. You can try it [here](http://www.searchforancestors.com/utility/metaphone.php)

Answer (score 0):

there is a UDF for mysql, which you can find here: http://joshdrew.com/

look for: [2004-02-06] - MySQL Levenshtein Distance UDF

you can use the Levenshtein Distance to calc a percentage difference.

this could look like:

(min(length('hello'), length('hollo')) - LevDist('hello', 'hollo')) / min(length('hello'), length('hollo'))

Comment: Levenstein distance will tell you that Raheem and Rahim 3 symbols away. As far as Raheem and Hakeem.

Comment: When i ll try i got the following error,mysqllevenshtein.cc:20:23: fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
how can i  resolve this and put into mysql?

Comment: you also could use a stored procedure like this: http://www.supermind.org/blog/927/working-mysql-5-1-levenshtein-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for an algorithm to compare the strings, or how to use such an algorithm in a sql query?

If you are asking the latter, create a user defined function that outputs the percentage based on 2 input strings, then select for every string in the table and filter where the percentage is above whatever threshold you are looking for.

So something like:

```
SELECT name, MyFuzzyStringComparer(name, @nameInQuestion) percentage 
FROM nameTable 
WHERE percentage > @threshold 
ORDER BY percentage
```

If you are looking for a comparison algorithm then the responses above seem to cover it.